# mac の open コマンドでサイトを開きたいがエラーが出る unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' syntax error unexpected end of file

Tags: macos

macでサイトをまとめて開きたく以下のコードを作って.commandで保存しました。

```
open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" "https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=○○" ; open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" "https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=○○" ;　・・・
```

ただ、これを実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
line1 unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line2 syntax error unexpected end of file
```

調べたらWindowsから作ったファイルからダウンロードしたのではないかというのがありましたが、Windowsから作られたファイルから開いていません。

Comment: 伏せ字になっているクエリワードの部分に "(ダブルクォート) が含まれていたりはしないでしょうか？

Comment: open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" "https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=元銀行員とんはるブログ" ; open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" "https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=元チャトレちまこのブログ" ;

このような感じで含まれてないと思います

Comment: なるほど、ダブルクォートではなくバッククォート(`0x60`)が問題になっているのだと思います。おそらく、ファイルが shift-jis で保存されているので、「元チャトレ」の「チ」の第2バイトが `0x60` になっているのでしょう。ファイルのエンコーディングを UTF-8 に変更してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！早速修正します

Comment: できました！本当ありがとうございます！